# Can Any one give me some hints?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Can Any one give me some **hints**? **Please dont give me the answer i still want to left some room for myself to think** .May anyone give me some advice so that i can solve the question

**Question:**
Let $K$ be a nonempty compact subset of $\mathbb R$. Prove that there exists a  bounded continuous function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that $K=\{ x \in \mathbb R:f(x)=0\}$

Comment: Hi Gillian, welcome to math.stackexchange. It will help people give you more useful answers to know a little more about where the question comes from and what you have already thought about. Is this question from a first course in real analysis? Or a topology course? And what is your current thinking about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hint for finding a continuous function $f$ whose zero set is exactly $K$. Once you find such a function, I bet you will be able to alter it so that it is also bounded.

Do you know the theorem that a continuous function on a compact set always takes on a maximum and a minimum value?

If you know this, then you can use it in the following way:

Let $K$ be a nonempty compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ as you said. Let $c$ be any point of $\mathbb{R}$ (in $K$ or not). We can use the above theorem to define a concept of *distance* between $c$ and $K$: basically, the distance between $c$ and the closest point of $K$ to it (which must exist because of compactness of $K$). How it works formally:

Consider the function $d(x) = |x-c|$. This is a continuous function of $x$. (This is **not** the function you're looking for. It's the distance between $c$ and $x$.) In particular, it is continuous on $K$. Since $K$ is compact, that means it has a minimum value on $K$. The minimum value of $d(x) = |x-c|$ as $x$ ranges over $K$ is called the *distance between $c$ and $K$*.

Question 1: if $c$ is actually in $K$, what's the distance between $c$ and $K$?

Question 2: if $c$ is not in $K$, what can you say about the distance between $c$ and $K$?

Comment: right. This is what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You need $K=[a, b]$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb R$, remember that a singleton $\{a\}$ is also compact.

Comment: I am thinking to take the complement of K ,then to construct an indicator function s.t. the function is equal to 0 if x is in K.Is it correct? but if i do in this way it is not necessary to require K is compact, so i get stuck

Comment: Try to think about what $K$ is, if you can some how get it so $K=\{ a \}$ for some $a \in \mathbb R$, think of a function where $f(x)=0$ at only one $x$

Comment: It looks like $K$ is given and not allowed to be altered in any way, while $f$ must be constructed around $K$. Urysohn's lemma comes to mind, and I think it proves existence of an $f$ such that $K\subseteq f^{-1}(0)$, but perhaps not necessarily $K= f^{-1}(0)$.

Comment: @GillianCheung - Your argument produces a function that is bounded and such that $K = \{x\in R: f(x) = 0\}$, however it is not continuous. That's why it didn't need compactness. To do it with a continuous function, you will need to use the fact that the set is compact.

Comment: @Alex - I'm not sure I understand the hint. The question wants $K$ to be an arbitrary compact set. A good answer would be able to produce a continuous function whose zero set is an arbitrary compact set such as the Cantor set. One could think of (bounded, continuous) functions whose zero sets are exactly $[a,b]$ and $\{a\}$, but still have no idea of a continuous function whose zero set is the Cantor set.

Comment: @BenBlum-Smith, I would begin with an unbounded continuous function that works, worry about boundedness later

Comment: @WillJagy - agreed, see my answer. Actually let me add that as a hint.

Comment: Yes my bad, $K$ should be arbitrary.